# How can I control time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In [IGN's interview with Notch about the changes in 1.8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcNgWEhlAxg), Notch seems to be able to change the time of day at a whim. Is this enabled by default (i.e., without mods), or is this a special Notch power?

Comment: Related for players of more recent versions: [Is there a way to change the time using cheats?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79906/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-time-using-cheats)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It *is* a special "Notch power" not available to players — it was used by the Minecraft developers for debugging. It was accidentally released in the first pre-release of Beta 1.8, but was taken out for the second one and the "stable beta" release.

The only way of controlling time is the operator-only [`/time` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/SMP_Server_commands) on multiplayer servers, which is instantaneous (unlike the effect shown in the video).

Comment: Or in 1.7 and below using SPC use the /time command.

Comment: I have confirmed this.  You were totally right about holding it down...

Comment: Doesn't make me sick :P looks pretty cool actually...

Comment: Unexpectedly, in beta 1.8pr2, F6/F7 don't work at all anymore, in neither game mode. I'll wait until the "stable beta" release before I touch this answer again.

Comment: It was never intended to be included in 1.8pre1. It's a debug feature accidentally included and it was removed in the next update: https://twitter.com/#!/jeb_/status/113729355087216640

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Well, thanks for that statement. I sort of assumed it was just broken in pr2, because it was a nifty feature and definitely had a use in Creative, like fast-forwarding to a dramatic sunset for a screenshot or getting rid of monsters. However, now that 1.8 is out, it looks like I'll have to do a 180° on my answer...

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to control the time of day in [creative mode](http://www.minecraftforum.net/news/199-pax-18-game-features/).

> 1.8 will add Creative Mode
>
> Since the Adventure mode will be replacing Survival, Mojang has also re-implemented Creative mode! In this mode, players will take no damage, be able to fly, **control day/night directly**, can spawn infinite items of any type, and can break blocks with one hit!

Comment: Ok, but that still leaves my question of "how"...

Comment: Scott C. - Your last post confuses the issue again, as it was plainly explained at the top that the changing of night/day was a mistake left in the 1.8 v1 pre-release. I don't think we're meant to have it, unless someone says otherwise. I mention this as the full 1.8 release is out as of this morning, and time cannot be altered with the F6 or F7 keys. (or we're you just quoting?) Nevermind....it'd be cool to have the time control.

Answer (score 2):

It's enabled by default in MineCraft 1.8-pre_release single-player.  In both Creative Game Mode and in Survival Game Mode.  Press <kbd>F6</kbd> to forward time and <kbd>F7</kbd> to rewind time.

As of Minecraft 1.8, you can no longer control time with <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>F7</kbd>, neither in Creative mode nor in Survival mode.

Comment: Wow, you're right, it *is* in both game modes. That's gotta be an oversight or a developer thing for the pre-release, though.

Comment: Dunno.  I'll check again when 1.8 is out.  I've edited my answer to explicitly say 1.8-pre-release.  Thanks lunboks

Comment: Updated my comment with regards to 1.8 stable.

Comment: It was a dev tool accidentally left in: https://twitter.com/#!/jeb_/status/113729355087216640