# Is there a way to change the time using cheats?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to change the time using cheats in Minecraft?

I'm thinking that a solution might involve commands, if so, what would they be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are running Minecraft 1.3 and above, you can use a command. Simply press <kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>/</kbd> key to open the console, type `/time set <time_of_day>`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit.

Note that `<time_of_day>` is in *ticks*, not seconds, minutes, or hours. This means the start of the day is `0`, nightfall is `12000`, and the end of the day is `24000` (which is equivalent to `0`).

---

If this does not work for you, this might be because cheats are not enabled in your world! [Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/277542/250180) is how to enable cheats on a world that has already been created.

Comment: I've tried that but nothing happens  :(

Comment: Is a button needed to open the console before typing in the command?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Yes, the `t` key. Added it to the answer.

Comment: I also want to add that you have to enable cheats for this to work
Which on creative is automatically enabled but on survival isnt

Comment: Shoot, that still doesn't work for me. I am on creative but maybe my cheats aren't on. How do i do that please?

Comment: @JimDel I think you have to create the world with cheats enabled. When did you create your world? And are you sure you're on 1.3? If your world is too old, there are programs to enable cheats. I'll updated my answer to accommodate.

Comment: I edited this answer to remove the tangent of enabling cheats on a world, instead linking to a [different question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/277542/250180) where that is the main topic.