# How to skip time in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been looking for an answer for a while I am designing a adventure map but I need a command for it. Is there any way for people to skip from one point of the day to the other.
Ex 1: I have a command once someone performs this one task from sunrise to afternoon
Ex 2: The 2nd player tries to perform this task but at the middle of the day then it progresses to evening
Is there any way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change time in creative mode of Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79906/is-there-a-way-to-change-time-in-creative-mode-of-minecraft)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `time` command like following:

```
/time add [TIME]
```

So to skip from sunrise to afternoon and from afternoon to night you must add `6500` ticks to the time by doing:

```
/time add 6500
```

Answer (score 0):

try ***/time set*** then morning is 0 and night is 18000

Answer (score -2):

try  /time day or night it tells you in /help how to change the time of day but it does not really fast foward anything

Comment: thank you for that I should keep that one for future reference always still learning nice to know!